# Angular and API Gateway: how to implement the PUT method?

Tags: angular, amazon-web-services, typescript, aws-api-gateway, put

I'm developing a Web Application with Angular 4 using TypeScript language (frontend side) and AWS with API Gateway (backend side).
I have a problem: the API Gateway is configured with a data update PUT Request which works perfectly.
if I use this code in my application (`correctUrl` is a string which refers to the correct url)

```
  putObject(myObject: MyObject) {
   if (this.authService.getAuthToken()) {
    let cognitoToken = this.authService.getAuthToken();
    let headers = new Headers({'Content-Type': 'application/json'}); 
    headers.append('Authorization', cognitoToken); //JWT token
    let url = correctUrl;

   return this.http.put(url, JSON.stringify(myObject) ,
          {headers})
      .map(data => data.json())
      .catch(this.handleError);
    } else {
        let errMsg = 'Error retrieving Authrization token from Cognito 
                      user session';
        console.error('error message: ' + errMsg);
        return Observable.throw(errMsg);
    }
  }
```

If I invoke this method (which seems to be correctly written), the PUT request is not executed (although the JSON object matches perfectly) and 
it appears on consoles: `Method PUT is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Methods in preflight response.`
This is very strange, because if i go to "Enable CORS", there are checkboxes in all three Methods: PUT, GET, OPTIONS (just because PUT has the check mark, I don't understand what the error is this.
I invoking a GET request in the same way and everything works perfectly, I don't explain because it does not happen the same with PUT!

Comment: You run the application in dev mode? I build it and put it on server then you not have to enable *cors* anymore..

Comment: How to enable this "dev mode"? Anyway I invoking get in the same way everything works perfectly, I don't explain because it does not happen the same with PUT!

Comment: Can you make post with a same example then with POST?
And preflight is mostly a header with OPTIONS that is send first.

Comment: the POST is not enabled, and I still need a put method

Comment: But you have already something working with this?

Comment: No, is the first time

Comment: Try to take a look in preflight and why it happen.

Comment: The problem is I don't know what to go to check! What is this "preflight"?

Comment: Google it you get 100+ hits.